# __call doesn't seem to work inside laravel console command

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm not sure why `__call` doesn't work in this scenario. Does it have to do with how  Command is implemented or am I doing something wrong?

```
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected $reports = [];

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = '';

    public function __call($methodName, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array($methodName, $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any entry in error log?

Comment: No errors, things working as normal.

Comment: I also tried the static method just for kicks same thing its not getting called

Comment: Could you pass the piece of code that you expect to result in __call being called?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the execute method if you are trying to extend the base Command class. This will essentially

```html
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface  $input
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface  $output
     * @return int
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // your custom logic here to be ran before all handlers, e.g.
        // setting up env variables, prompting user, ...
        
        $method = method_exists($this, 'handle') ? 'handle' : '__invoke';

        return (int) $this->laravel->call([$this, $method]);
    }
```